# Check if Excel is empty

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a bunch of excel files automatically generated by a process. However, some of them are empty because the process stopped before actually writing anything. These excels do not even contain any columns, so they are just an empty sheet.

I'm now runnin some scripts on each of the excels, so I would like to check if the excel is empty, and if so, skip it.

I have tried:

```
pandas.DataFrame.empty
```

But I still get the message:  `EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

How can I perform this check?

Comment: try: `pandas.DataFrame().empty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not using a try/except:

```
try:
    # try reading the excel file
    df = pd.read_excel(…) # or pd.read_csv(…)
except pd.errors.EmptyDataError:
    # do something else if this fails
    df = pd.DataFrame()
```

Comment: You are absolutely right! I do not know how I did not think about that. Thanks!